# Previous month number in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to do a vlookup where the criteria is a month number. The month number must be the previous month of the selected cell. So if the cell is Apr(4), then the  result/criteria should be Mar (3), and if the selected cell is Jan(1) the result/criteria should be 12.

I know this can be done using Excel formula like EOMONTH etc but  am looking for only a mathematical approach.

Comment: =MONTH(EDATE(A1,-1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mathematical formula is `(Month+10)%12+1`.

In Excel notation this becomes `MOD(Month+10,12)+1`.

`Month` is an integer (1 to 12), a cell reference, or a formula to extract the month from a cell containing a date (eg `MONTH(Date)`).

Answer (score 0):

**Since any mathematical solution need to be converted with LOOKUP function so that you may use this as a complete solution using Excel Formula:**

[image]

*You can use either of the Formulas:*

`{=VLOOKUP(EDATE($A6,-1),$A$2:$C$4,{2,3},FALSE)}`

- Enter Lookup Date in `A6` and Formula in `B6` then Fill Right, Press `F2` and finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- Enter this Formula in `B7:`

  `=VLOOKUP(DATE(YEAR($A6),MONTH($A6)-1,DAY($A6)),$A$2:$C$4,2,FALSE)`